# Display Title Number Onscreen in PotPlayer or VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player, daum-pot-player

I would like to display the Title Number of the track that is currently playing in PotPlayer or VLC. Currently, I click through a series of dropdown menus to get to this information.

Is there a way to display the Title Number when the track begins to play? Or an easier way to find it?

[image: PotPlayer]

[image: VLC]

Comment: I don't have the answer but if you're using VLC with a playlist you can toggle Control-L (display/undisplay playlist) and visually interpret relative position. Very least, that will show the title even if you are not using a playlist. I KNOW that's lame but I'm just trying to lead you to something better than the fatiguing menu navigation. I've seen people ask for a way to simply show Title and Chapter, but the lead VLC developer (Jean-Baptiste. French guy) is a major dick about that from what I've seen of him and his attitude on the VLC forum when asked about that specifically. Rotsa Ruck :(